# What's outside of the universe?

Tags: cosmology, spacetime, universe

Assuming you found a way and managed to accelerate above light speed without disintegrating, and went to the edge of the universe, what would happen?

Would you instantly explode due to the lack of physics after you went out, or would there be an invisible unbreakable wall? Or, would you even find another universe with completely different laws of physics? Or would the atoms that go outside of the universe simply pop out of existence?

Sorry if this is a bit unrelated, it has been nagging at me for a long time, and I couldn't concentrate on anything.

Comment: It is not certain (in fact, highly unlikely) that the universe has "an edge".

Comment: Semantically, the question is meaningless.  The Universe is the totality of all that exists. If something exists outside of some notion of "the boundary of the universe", then that choice of boundary bounds something less than the Universe.  But I note that in the context of an omniverse hypothesis, the meaning of the word "universe" has been degraded.

Comment: If I may summarize, you are basically asking the following: "Assuming you did something that defies known physics, what does known physics say would happen afterward?"

Comment: @garyp: While I agree with the rest of your comment, I am not sure the concept of the word universe has actually been degraded, it's just not being used properly by the folks who are in awe with a diversity of multi-verse scenarios. The proper way of using the word, in my opinion, is to say that there is a theoretical possibility that "the universe" may separate into leafs or compartments that are almost completely isolated. That is an enrichment of the structure of "the universe" rather than a degradation. It is a degradation of our ability to experience "the universe", of course.

Comment: @CuriousOne I think we agree exactly. I might rephrase:  the meaning of the word has been degraded by some who misuse it.  (And this is one step toward general degradation.)  It does seem that the misuse of the word in popular press is ... universal.  ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Assuming you found a way and managed to accelerate above light speed without disintegrating, and went to the edge of the universe...**

I'm confident you can't go faster than light, but when it comes to the edge of the universe, I'm also confident that nobody knows any answers. However people say they do and state categorically that there is no edge. For example see [this NASA page](http://map.gsfc.nasa.gov/universe/uni_shape.html) which says this: *"We now know (as of 2013) that the universe is flat with only a 0.4% margin of error. This suggests that the Universe is infinite in extent"*. I'm afraid it doesn't suggest that at all. Yes we have some confidence that the universe is flat so you don't end up going round in circles. But we just don't know what lies beyond the observable universe. And I for one am very uncomfortable with the idea of an infinite universe. Not just because it opens the door to multiverse pseudoscience, but how can an infinite universe expand? How does that sit with big bang cosmology? Not well. I don't like it. It's so problematical that I'm prepared to think of the universe as having some kind of edge.

**what would happen?**

Nobody knows. But it's interesting to talk about it.

**Would you instantly explode due to the lack of physics after you went out**

Like garyp suggested, I don't think you can go out. The edge of the universe is the edge of space. *There is no space beyond the edge of space*. There is no place to go.

**Or would there be an invisible unbreakable wall?**

Actually, there is a sense where maybe there could. Imagine a droplet of water. Wavelets inside the droplet get to the edge of the droplet and then undergo total internal reflection. Waves in space might be something like that. The edge of space serves as an invisible unbreakable wall. Waves in space can't get past it.

**Or, would you even find another universe with completely different laws of physics?**

No. The universe is everything. If you found yourself in a place where physics was different, it would just be some other region of this universe.

**Or would the atoms that go outside of the universe simply pop out of existence?**

There is no going outside the universe. And if there was some kind of edge I can't see how anything would pop out of existence. Maybe nothing could ever reach it. If somehow you could maybe you'd see light waves bouncing back. Maybe the edge looks like a mirror. Maybe matter bounces back too, because of the wave nature of matter. Or maybe it's something like a black hole event horizon, where you get kind of frozen by the time dilation. But maybe it's something like the mooted [black hole firewall](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firewall_(physics)). KABOOM! You get destroyed. You don't pop out of existence, you go out of existence with a bang. But like I said, nobody knows, and that includes me. Maybe there's no edge at all.

Comment: "how can an infinite universe expand?" to my untrained ear this doesn't sound that unbelievable. I'm thinking of a simple R^n=>R^n map like x->2x. Something like that maps R^n (an infinite space) onto itself, pushing points close together further apart.

Comment: @whitman : I was thinking in terms of pressure that is counterbalanced at all locations.

Answer (score 0):

Light speed travel is impossible, so you are asking what happens to a system when we totally ignore the system. Aside from that, the universe probably does not have an edge. The observable universe does have an edge, but you can never reach it. This is because when you move, the the edge of your observable universe moves with you.